# Dynamically using SQL statements for SQLDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, sqldatasource

I may or may not have a pretty simple question here for you guys.  Basing my if-else statements off of the existence of a string, I am trying to either call a SELECT statement with a parameter or not and pass them both to the same resulting GridView.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
 string query;
 if(BadgeNumLabel.Text != "")
 {
     query = "SELECT * FROM AUDITS";
 else
 {
     query = "SELECT * FROM AUDITS WHERE BADGENUM = :BadgeNumLabel";
     GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("BadgeNumLabel",TypeCode.String, BadgeNumLabel.Text));
 }

 GridDataSource.SelectCommand = query;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

My .aspx code looks like this:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConnectionString.ProviderName %>"  
            onselecting="GridDataSource_Selecting">


        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there something I am missing?  I am so stumped.  I think it has to do something with passing the parameter BadgeNumLabel around but I'm not sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: where your're passing the parameter value?. Also do you test that sql query?

Comment: I tried using this:

GridDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("BadgeNumLabel", TypeCode.String, BadgeNumLabel.Text));

But it didn't work.

Comment: so you mean, you don't get any result when you run?

Comment: It throws an exception when doing the databind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of the `GridDataSource` to the `GridView1.DataSource`

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand GridDataSource= new SqlCommand();

GridDataSource.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM AUDITS";
GridDataSource.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
GridDataSource.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

GridView1.DataSource = GridDataSource.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**EDIT**

It's not literally ExecuteCommand, what I try to say is that you need to assign the result of the SqlCommand to the `GridView`

Comment: It says I don't have an assembly reference to GridDataSource.ExecuteCommand when I enter that line.

Comment: Where would you use the 'SqlDataReader' object above.  It looks like you have created it but haven't used it.

Also, if I already have a SQLDataSource created, would I have to go about opening up a new connection?

Comment: Ok, I just deleted the `SqlDataReader`. You should run this fast example just add the connection String and if it works, then you're sure the problem is that you're not assigning the resulting query to the `GridView1.DataSource`.